# Add List to ListView in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I am new to using Xamarin in Visual Studio and I am a bit confused how to use ListViews.

I have a simple List:

```
private List<string> laplist = new List<string>();
```

In which there are a few strings looking like this:

```
Lap 1: 00:01:00.1000
```

I would now like to show that list on my Android App.

I tried following the official example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/, but I do not understand it.

Could someone be so kind and explain how exactly I can either Databind it or simply put the text into the ListView?

I do not think it is necessary, but here's also the AXML:

```
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/laplist" />
```

Comment: You are mixing Android native layouts/controls vs Xamarin.Forms-based document about data binding. Are you developing an Xamarin.Android and using native layouts (AXML), or trying to use Xamarin.Forms (XAML) to describe your app's UI?

Comment: "But I don't understand it." - what specifically don't you understand?  It's useless for us to write up another tutorial/example that covers the same material the existing one does.

Comment: @SushiHangover It is an .axml

Comment: @ITnoob You need to look at data "adapters" for Android-Tased ListViews/RecyclerViews/... : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/populating

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, I'll try

Comment: Check this if you need more help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/xamarin-android-listview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XAML then you need to use Xamarin.Forms. Otherwise o Android passing the data is done through the Adapter which is assigned to the ListView in the backend code.